# Where to put method call so it execute at every 5 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have below code :

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var cronExpressionVal = new Timer(async e => await GetCronExpression(cancellationToken), null, TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is, `GetCronExpression` method should run at every 5 minutes.

But my problem is, when we first time run programme so it is coming in `StartAsync` method.

And it execute successfully.

Now it is not coming again in this method so my `GetCronExpression` method is not calling at every 5 minutes.

So my question is where should I put this `GetCronExpression` method call so it execute at every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to achieve is, GetCronExpression method should run at
> every 5 minutes.

Well, couple of ways to handle this. However, the most efficient and easiest way to meet your requirement is to use [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-6.0). Importantly, you don't need to think where should you keep this. You can call your method every `5 minutes` time interval from everywhere. It could be within `middleware` or `any custom class` , repository, even from `controller`.

**Implementation Using Middleware:**

```
public class AutoTimerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public AutoTimerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {


            var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            int counter = 0;
            while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
            {
                counter++;
               // if (counter > 5) break;
                CallThisMethodEvery5Second(counter);
            }
            // Move forward into the pipeline
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        public void CallThisMethodEvery5Second(int counter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current counter: {0} Last Fired At: {1}", counter, DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** When use in middleware, please register in `program.cs` file as following

```
app.UseMiddleware<AutoTimerMiddleware>();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Implementation Using Any Custom Class/Anywhere:**

```
            var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            int counter = 0;
            while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
            {
                counter++;
                if (counter > 5) break;
                CallThisMethodEvery5Second(counter);
            }
```

Note: You will call your method `GetCronExpression` within the `WaitForNextTickAsync` so that will be called at your given time frame. For the demo, I am calling this in every 5 seconds.

**Method To Call:**

```
public void CallThisMethodEvery5Second(int counter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current counter: {0} Last Fired At: {1}",counter, DateTime.Now);
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep reference to timer otherwise it will be garbage collected:

> As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-7.0#remarks

If it's not the case, I suggest including more context.